# How can I change the language in chromium?

Tags: chrome, i18n

I've installed chromium, but it deeply sucks that it uses my mother tongue (german) in its UI and for websites by default.

I want the english back, like firefox did. I'm using archlinux's default packages. I looked into the settings dialogs, but I found nothing useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use version **6.0.472.63** and I found **Change font and language settings** under **Customize and control Chromium** --> **Options** --> **Under the hood**.

Answer (score 9):

After trying many solutions that did not work for me, here's something that just worked fine.

```
 sudo apt-get install chromium-browser-l10n
```

Answer (score 5):

There is a preference to set the language preference for web pages: in the “Preferences” dialog ([which may be called differently in your version](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6220/how-can-i-change-the-language-in-chromium/6221#6221)), in the “Under the Hood” tab, click “Change font and language settings”.

This doesn't give you full control (you can only select languages that Chrome knows about, and there won't be a `*` at the end to make the server fall back on whatever it has available if it doesn't happen to know your language). In the `Preferences` file in your profile (i.e. typically `~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Preferences`), you can tune the setting more finely:

{
     "intl": {
        "accept_languages": "en_US,en_GB,en,de_DE,de,*",
     },
   }

(The syntax is [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). Edit the existing `"intl"` section.)

---

The language of the user interface is determined by the `LC_MESSAGES` environment variable, which is the standard setting under unix. At least, this is the case for Google Chrome 9.0.597.45 under Debian (from [Google's apt repository](http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/)); Chromium under Ubuntu lucid seems determined to speak to me in English.